# Add field dynamically in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

[Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8a6e.jpg)

In the Service Provided field, I want to add more text box dynamically,when the user wants to add more than one service name. How to achieve that?

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
        customer_username = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        website = models.URLField()
        office_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        service_provided = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contact = models.IntegerField()
        city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        zip_code = models.IntegerField()
        number_of_employee = models.IntegerField()
        establishment_year = models.IntegerField()
        number_of_project_done = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.organisation_name
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import CustomerProfile

    class CustomerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = CustomerProfile
            fields = '__all__'
            exclude = ('customer_username',)
```

Comment: Use Django formset_factory OR more suitable in your case JQuery / Javascript to add more forms.

Comment: Your model allows each `CustomerProfile` to have a single service. If you want to allow multiple services for each profile, you'll need to rethink your models (e.g. have a `Service` model with a foreign key to `CustomerProfile`.

Comment: .My objective is that user can add service by clicking on plus button, without reloading the page. Can you pls provide some code for that @Alasdair

Comment: No, I can't write that code for you. Even if you write that code, your current model only allows one service to be stored for each profile. My point is that you should fix your model before you go any further.

Comment: ok got it. Thanks for the help@Alasdair

Comment: Use JQuery / Javascript to add more text boxes dynamically. But your model does not support it. Either you need to store it as a single text `service1, service2, service3` - give a bigger length for it or have a `Service` model separately which would be a foreign reference in the `CustomerProfile` model.

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically add fields in the init override of your form class.

Example of the init method (put something like this in your form class):

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomerProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['test_field'] = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
```

You have to use other solutions if you want to add more fields on the page itself without reloads.